# Struct C/C++ - Reading WAV Header 32 Bit Float - byte offset wrong

Tags: c++, wav

I use a struct for reading Wav-Files in audio format 3 (=IEEE FLOAT 32 Bit) with a 58 byte wav-header. The problem: Byte 38 starts with the "fact" chunk. This seems to be ok. DwFactSize should have an offset of 42. Here the problem begins! The offset is 44 !!! First I thought, the problem is in padding bits. So I tried uints, unsigned chars and **attribute**((packed)). This doesn't change anything.

This is the definition of the wav header:

> 0  - 3     'RIFF'/'RIFX' Little/Big-endian
>
> 4  - 7     wRiffLength   length of file minus the 8 byte riff header
>
> 8  - 11    'WAVE'
>
> 12 - 15    'fmt '
>
> 16 - 19    wFmtSize       length of format chunk minus 8 byte header
>
> 20 - 21    wFormatTag     identifies PCM, ULAW etc
>
> 22 - 23    wChannels
>
> 24 - 27    dwSamplesPerSecond  samples per second per channel
>
> 28 - 31    dwAvgBytesPerSec    non-trivial for compressed formats
>
> 32 - 33    wBlockAlign         basic block size
>
> 34 - 35    wBitsPerSample      non-trivial for compressed formats

(until byte 35 like the usual 44 byte header)

> 36 - 37    wExtSize = 0  the length of the format extension
>
> 38 - 41    'fact'
>
> 42 - 45    dwFactSize = 4  length of the fact chunk minus 8 byte
>   header
>
> 46 - 49    dwSamplesWritten   actual number of samples written out
>
> 50 - 53    'data'
>
> 54 - 57    dwDataLength  length of data chunk minus 8 byte header

---

### output:

...

until here ... correct...

Fact[4] 38

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

DwFactSize 44

dwSamplesWritten 48

Data[4] 52

dwDataLength 56

Quick hack to show the offset problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

typedef struct  WAV_HEADER
{
unsigned char       RIFF[4];        /* RIFF Header      */ //Magic header
unsigned long       ChunkSize;      /* RIFF Chunk Size  */
unsigned char       WAVE[4];        /* WAVE Header      */
unsigned char       fmt[4];         /* FMT header       */
unsigned long       Subchunk1Size;  /* Size of the fmt chunk: 16=PCM, 18=IEEE Float, 40=Extensible                     */
unsigned short      AudioFormat;    /* Audio format 1=PCM, 3=IEEE Float, 6=mulaw,7=alaw, 257=IBM Mu-Law, 258=IBM A-Law, 259=ADPCM, 65534=Extensible */
unsigned short      NumOfChan;      /* Number of channels 1=Mono 2=Stereo                   */
unsigned long       SamplesPerSec;  /* Sampling Frequency in Hz                             */
unsigned long       bytesPerSec;    /* bytes per second */
unsigned short      blockAlign;     /* 2=16-bit mono, 4=16-bit stereo , 6=24-bit stereo,8=32-bit stereo*/
unsigned short      bitsPerSample;  /* Number of bits per sample, inkl. hier=36 bytes  */
unsigned short      wExtSize;       /*  2 byte, wExtSize = 0  the length of the format extension   */
unsigned char       Fact[4];        /* "fact"  string   */
/*Problem here! -> +2bytes*/
unsigned long       DwFactSize;     /* Sampled data length,  inkl. hier bei 44 bytes */
unsigned long       dwSamplesWritten;
unsigned char       Data[4];        /* leerer string falls extensible -> Beginn nicht nach 44 sondern 68!  */
unsigned long       dwDataLength;   /* raw DataLength */
}__attribute__((packed)) wav_hdr;


int getFileSize(FILE *inFile);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
char *file;
file = argv[1];
wav_hdr wavHeader;
FILE *wavFile;
int headerSize = sizeof(wav_hdr),filelength = 0;
wavFile = fopen(file,"r");
if(wavFile == NULL)
{
    printf("\nCan not open wave file. Usage: program [file] \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fread(&wavHeader,headerSize,1,wavFile);
filelength = getFileSize(wavFile);
fclose(wavFile);


std::cout << "\nRIFF " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, RIFF) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nChunkSize " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, ChunkSize) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nWAVE[4] " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, WAVE) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nfmt[4] " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, fmt) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nSubchunk1Size " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, Subchunk1Size) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nAudioFormat " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, AudioFormat) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nNumOfChan " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, NumOfChan) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nSamplesPerSec " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, SamplesPerSec) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nbytesPerSec " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, bytesPerSec) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nblockAlign " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, blockAlign) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nbitsPerSample " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, bitsPerSample) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nwExtSize (2) " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, wExtSize) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nFact[4] " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, Fact) <<  std::endl;

std::cout << "\nDwFactSize " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, DwFactSize) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\ndwSamplesWritten " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, dwSamplesWritten) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\nData[4] " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, Data) <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "\ndwDataLength " << offsetof(WAV_HEADER, dwDataLength) <<  std::endl;


return 0;
}

int getFileSize(FILE *inFile)
{
int fileSize = 0;
fseek(inFile,0,SEEK_END);
fileSize=ftell(inFile);
fseek(inFile,0,SEEK_SET);
return fileSize;
}
```

To generate such a 32 Bit Float, 88200 Wav-file:
sox input16_44100.wav -b 32 -e float output32F_88200.wav rate -s -a -v -L 88200

Comment: Off-ish topic (If it was on topic, your offsets would be way, way off) are you absolutely certain of the sizes of `short` and `long`? Might be better to use   [fixed-width integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)

Comment: On-ish topic, what happens if you read the fields one by one rather than counting on your structure's packing to match the writer's?

Comment: Like I wrote, I used unsigned char, uint16_t, uint32_t ... the same after the fact-chunk. This works since years for 44 byte headers ...

Comment: @TJF Is by anychance this question was given for a job application?

Comment: What about the PEAK header?

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 bytes of padding between `Fact[]` and `DwFactSize`, obviously.

I suspect it's because you're using a `typedef` there. Just write it as a regular C++ definition: `struct __attribute__((packed)) WAV_HEADER { ...`

Comment: Yes, the 2 bytes are the problem. I tried your suggestion... but without success..

Comment: When I do this, the header size is correct:

    unsigned char   DwFactSize[4]; 
            
    unsigned char   dwSamplesWritten[4]; 
      
    unsigned char   Data[4];
   
    unsigned char   dwDataLength[4];       

But what is the reason? This would be hardly usable...

Comment: @TJF: Padding is inserted to enforce alignment restrictions, but `char` has no alignment restrictions. I'd recommend `uint32_t DataLength() const` -  a function, not a data member.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more or do you have any example ...?

Comment: @TJF: See [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20alignment) - plenty of good info already there.

Comment: I solved it by using the last struct parts with single chars [], like I wrote above ...